Instrumental variables with lags?
I am new to econometrics so I was hoping to get help with something I didn't understand very well. I have the following regression model:
$$G_t=\beta_0+M_{t}+\epsilon_{t} $$
$G_t$ stands for GDP growth in year t.
$M_t$ stands for military spending in year t.
I am using an instrumental variable $I_{t}$ for $M_t$.
BUT, suppose I want to add a lag of military spending to the above regression model, so that my new model is:
$$G_t=\beta_0+M_{t}+MS_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t} $$
I now have two endogenous variables $MS_t$ and $M_{t-1}$, so I need another instrument. Can I just use $I_{t-1}$, which is the lagged value of my original instrumental variable $I_t$, as a second instrumental variable in this case?
